# Different results when using atoi() for C in Mac OS X and Ubuntu

Tags: c, glibc, atoi

Here's the code which I ran on Mac OS X (10.8.1, 64-bit and 10.6.8, 32-bit) and Ubuntu (10.04, 32-bit):

```
printf("%d\n", atoi("2147483648"));
// returns -2147483648 in Mac OS X 10.8.1 and 10.6.8
// returns 2147483647 in Ubuntu
```

Here's what I found after some Googling: http://gynvael.coldwind.pl/?id=365

Is there any reason why the output varies on different systems?

Comment: IIRC Any value which cannot be represented in the type its being converted to has its value defined by the implementation. In your case libc just returns INT_MAX and in Mac OS you get an overflow

Comment: Ubuntu 32-bit or 64-bit?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not surprising, because the behavior [is not specified](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/atoi/) by the standard:

> There is no standard specification on what happens when the converted value would be out of the range of representable values by an int.

The [`strtol`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/strtol/) function gives you more info in the return, as it sets `errno` to `ERANGE` when the value does not fit in a `long int`.